# Using of updated value in AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, assemblyinfo

I'm trying to figure out, how to process and update value in `AssemblyInfo.cs` of `C#` `WinForms` desktop application.

For example, where and how to process

```
string currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
```

and update in `AssemblyInfo.cs` to always get only `currentYear` with particular `.exe` -> `Properties/Details` -> `description - Product name` from

```
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Access described according " + currentYear + " year update")]
```

Any advice, guide or example would be useful

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to use [compile-time T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017#design-time-t4-text-templates).

I'm currently on a Mac, so I'm unable to test this (.NET Core apparently requires different tools), but maybe creating an `AssemblyInfo.cs.tt` file with contents like

```
<#@ template hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
string currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
#>
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// [... snip ...]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("Something from year <#= currentYear #>")]
```

might work for you?

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure how to adapt this way in WinForms